# Error in utilizing Endpoint generated library( in Android) : constructor AbstractGoogleJsonClient(...) is undefined

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I am in the process of learning to utilize the Endpoint generated library in Android application. I am trying to bring up the below mentioned sample program 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-android

Everything is fine ; except for the error given below. I just could not resolve this.

```
Error -> The constructor AbstractGoogleJsonClient(HttpTransport, JsonFactory, 
String, String, HttpRequestInitializer, boolean) is undefined
```

When I extracted the class file AbstractGoogleJsonClient.java  from Jar ; given below is the content I could see. Can some-one let me know what needs to be done here to resolve the error?

```
public abstract class AbstractGoogleJsonClient extends AbstractGoogleClient {

  protected AbstractGoogleJsonClient(Builder builder) {
    super(builder); 
  } 

  public abstract static class Builder extends AbstractGoogleClient.Builder {

    protected Builder(HttpTransport transport, JsonFactory jsonFactory, 
                    String rootUrl, String servicePath, HttpRequestInitializer 
                    httpRequestInitializer, boolean legacyDataWrapper) { 

       super(transport, rootUrl, servicePath, new JsonObjectParser.Builder( 

          jsonFactory).setWrapperKeys( 

          legacyDataWrapper ? Arrays.asList("data", "error") : Collections.
                                       <String>emptySet()) 

          .build(), httpRequestInitializer); 

    }
```

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 3):

[In the read file](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-android/blob/master/README.md), it is stated that the project depends on  **google-api-client-1.13.2-beta.jar**
I had the same error because I added higher version of the google api client library to my project.

Try adding  ***1.13.2-beta*** version of google api client to your project, which worked on me. You can get it from [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/api-client/google-api-client/1.13.2-beta/google-api-client-1.13.2-beta.jar)